# Angular Universal + PM2: Keeps exiting and restarting

Tags: angular, pm2, angular-universal, angular7

I created an Angular 7 application with Angular Universal for SSR. Testing locally, I can see the static contents rendering without any problem.

```
npm run build:prod && npm run server -o
```

However, once the file `server.js` and folders `server` and `browser` are deployed to the server and after starting the application as root user using

`pm2 start server.js`

it gives me the following:

[image]

```
PM2      | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [server:0] online
PM2      | App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [server:0] online
PM2      | App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [server:0] online
PM2      | App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [server:0] online
PM2      | App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [server:0] online
PM2      | App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [server:0] online
PM2      | App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
```

As expected, pm2 restarts the application once it exited. The problems is that the application seems to exit immediately after it is started.

Alternatively, issuing

`node server.js`

does the same: the application executes and returns to the shell prompt without any message.

Any ideas might be causing the problem? TIA

Comment: Have you tried to run your application with node inspector enabled? "node --inspect server.js" to look where appears the error.

Answer (score 3):

don't run server.js file directly.

Create **local.js** file

```
local.js

    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
    const server = require('./dist/server'); 
    server.app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on: http://localhost:${port}`); });
```

put the local.js file in your project and then run **local.js** using **pm2**

myProject

- dist folder
- local.js